# Why OpenMP 'simd' has better performance than 'parallel for simd'?

Tags: c++, performance, concurrency, openmp

I'm working on a Intel E5 (6 cores, 12 threads) with intel compiler OpenMP 4.0

Why is this piece of code SIMD-ed quicker than parallel SIMD-ed?

```
for (int suppv = 0; suppv < sSize; suppv++) {
  Value *gptr = &grid[gind];
  const Value * cptr = &C[cind];

  #pragma omp simd // vs. #pragma omp parallel for simd
  for (int suppu = 0; suppu < sSize; suppu++)
    gptr[suppu] += d * cptr[suppu];

  gind += gSize;
  cind += sSize;
}
```

And with more threads, it becomes slower.

---

Edit 1:
  * `grid` is a 4096*4096 matrix, data structure: `vector<complex<double>>`
  * `C` is a `2112*129*129` matrix, data structure: `vector<complex<double>>`
  * gSize = 4096
  * sSize = 129.

- Compiler flags: icpc -march=native -std=c++11 -qopt-report-phase=vec -qopt-report=3 -O2 -openmp
- Timer: use POSIX times() API's return value diff. (It does use wall clock for concurrency, I did the check)
- E5 thread  1 SIMD takes: 291.520000 (s)
- E5 thread  2 for-SIMD takes: 1039.220000 (s)
- E5 thread 12 for-SIMD takes: 1684.270000 (s)

Comment: How much slower? How did you measure it? Did you examine the assembly? Did you try to leave the number of threads to be the same as your number of cores?

Comment: How big is `sSize`?  As `grid` and `C` contiguous, why two loops (ah, only operating on prefixes of `C` stuff, strange).  Is anything else parallel?  Cam you demonstrate this in a small program?  What are your compiler flags, and what are the actual times recorded?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `sSize` = 129, as you have in your edit, then the overhead of parallelizing the loop doesn't pay off. This would be easier to confirm if you'd  show us the numbers of the sequential implementation (no SIMD) and the pure parallel implementation (i.e. with `#pragma omp parallel for` but no SIMD).

What is likely happening is that even the pure parallel version is slower than the sequential one. Not only the loop size is reduced, as you launch/create a parallel zone for every iteration of the outer-most loop.

As for the SIMD version, this problem is essentially tailored for that: you have a highly vectorizable kernel that would be too small to distribute among threads.

Comment: Bingo. Kicking off worker thread tasks is useful if each one is going to do a *lot* of work. Parallelizing 129 add/muls is several orders of magnitude away from being a good idea.